# How do I declaratively configure hashicorp vault with Kubernetes/minikube?

Tags: kubernetes, hashicorp-vault

I followed this tutorial for deploying vault into a minikube cluster: https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/vault/kubernetes-minikube?in=vault/kubernetes.

I don't understand, however, how this is reproducible. These seem like a lot of manual steps. Is there a way to easily deploy these pods again if I destroy them? Would I need to script this or can I somehow get the consul and vault pods, output them as yaml and use that to recreate them?

Answer (score 1):

I found this blog post on hashicorp's site which seems to address configuration once you are up and running: https://www.hashicorp.com/blog/codifying-vault-policies-and-configuration.

There's also this: https://kubevault.com/docs/v2021.08.02/welcome/

Setting it up before the API is running seems to require either manual steps or a pretty simple shell script.